# Resetting a loop in a loop

Tags: c++, stl, for-loop, unordered-map

I am very curious to learn why the below code does not run in a continuous loop.  And I'm also looking for some ways to achieve what I want to achieve--which is resetting a loop inside of the loop.  I need to do this because I need to account for each element in a container.  The reason why this is because I might start off in the middle, and need to loop back around to check the others / and need to recheck other information too.  So on with my little test example:

```
for ( int i = 0; i != 10; i++ ) {
    std::cout << std::endl << "TEST: " << i << std::endl;
    if ( i++ == 10 ) {
        i = 0;
    } else {
        i--;
    }
}
```

Is there any particular reason why the above does not work?  I am very interested in knowing why, so I can learn how everything works.  This also leads into a much bigger problem I am facing.  Which is the below code.  I am using MSVC++ 2010 Express.  Also, this is one thread, so other data is not accessing it.  It is an unordered_map using STL.  its size if 2 (i checked).

```
for (game_player_client_map::const_iterator it = gpc_map_ptr->begin(); it != gpc_map_ptr->end(); ++it) {
    if ( it++ == gpc_map_ptr->end() ) {
        cout << endl << "IT == gpc_map_ptr->end()" << endl;
        it = gpc_map_ptr->begin();
    } else {
        it--;
    }
}
```

I appreciate any feedback SO has to offer, and any new things to learn :-)  If further information is needed I will provide.  Thank you for your time.

Comment: `i=9; std::cout << i++;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the condition is checked before the body of the loop is entered. When `i == 10`, the loop is broken, before your code can execute at the time that `i++` would evaluate to 10.

Remember that postincrement increments the variable and returns the *old value*. So if `i` is 9, `i++` evaluates to 9 also, but the next time you use `i`, it will be 10.

If you want the variable to be incremented and use the new value in an expression, use preincrement:

```
if (++i == 10) // changes i to i + 1 and checks if the new value of i is 10
```

You could completely ditch the increment however, and just use `i + 1`. That way you don't have to de-increment `i` in the `else` block.

Your misunderstanding of postincrement is probably also the source of the bug in the second block of code you posted. You can change it to preincrement, or if `it` is a random-access iterator, you can do the same thing as mentioned above and check if `it + 1 == gpc_map_ptr->end()` and not have to de-increment `it` in the `else` block.

Comment: Thank you so much Seth.  I had no idea about post and pre increments.  And this new information will will become very valuable.  SO amazes me yet again.

Comment: @Ohmages yes, using post/pre increment in expressions is tricky, using the right one is vital.